# What API does iOS have to write Web proxy?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, firefox, safari, webproxy

Does IOS provide API to write a proxy program for IPad /IPhone to process web requests from Safari, Chrome, Firefox and also apps that work with UIWebView?
Can this proxy also work as a daemon? I need this proxy to periodically create web usage statistics and generate summary reports.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about writing a program and is not a general purpose hardware - try on AskDifferent

Comment: Changed the question to make it more specific